# How can I identify columns independent from language?

Tags: list, column, language

I've got a webpart which reads several values from a list, while developing local I've got a column "Due Date", but when I upload my webpart to SharePoint online (Office 365) we have a German version and the column is called "Fälligkeitsdatum" so my code doesn't work (without changing the columnname in the source everytime).

How can I read the column independent from language? Is this possible with guid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SPField.InternalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.internalname.aspx).

You can see what the Internal Name in several ways, such as in List Settings, or in AllItems (url when sorting by a field).

Internal Name of "Due Date" in Tasks list is **DueDate**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should use the GUID

The GUID of a lot of the BuiltIn Fields are abailable in [SPBuiltInFieldId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms435407.aspx) regarding Due Date use [SPBuiltInFieldId.DueDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.duedate.aspx)

Comment: Could you provide a sample? I can't get it to work: Invalid field name. {c1e86ea6-7603-493c-ab5d-db4bbfe8f96a}

Comment: Sounds like you are passing in a GUID as a string and not as a GUID object. You can convert a string to a GUID using `Guid fieldId = new Guid(guidAsString);`

Comment: Unfortunatly not :-( SPBuiltInFieldId.DueDate is already a Guid.

Comment: Ohhhh sorry the mistake was that I used DueDate, but as I'm using a tasklist I needed to use TaskDueDate. Your code works perfect thanks :-)